# Create a matrix of list without for loop in R

Tags: r

I have two list in R and I want to create the result in a matrix for different `z` values. Means that at the end I have matrix with 2 rows and 10 columns.

```
x = list(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
y = list(a = 4, b = 5, c =  3)
z = seq(0, 1, len = 10)
w = list(a1 = z * x$a + (1-z) * x$b + x$c , b1 = z * y$a + (1-z) * y$b + y$c)
```

How can I do this without for loop in R?

Comment: How would you do it *with* a `for` loop?  (It is not at all clear what you want.)

Comment: I didn't do it with for loop, but I think with for loop we should create a matrix of zero then fill out each element with unlist the w vector elements.

Comment: So you want to turn `w` into a matrix? This should do the trick `do.call("rbind", w)`. FYI - you are missing a mathematical operator in `a1`, probably intended to be `*` based on `b1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rbind(unlist(x), unlist(y)) %*% rbind(z, 1-z, 1)
```

Comment: If the length of unlist(x) and unlist(y) was not 2 , so we can not use this code. What should we do in this regards?

Comment: See, it also works with your new example. After I added a row of `1` to the weight matrix on the right.

Comment: I get this result:>  rbind(unlist(x), unlist(y)) %*% rbind(z, 1-z)
Error in rbind(unlist(x), unlist(y)) %*% rbind(z, 1 - z) : 
  non-conformable arguments

Comment: If we want to create w = list(a1 = z * x$a + (1-z) * y$a + x$c , b1 = z * x$b + (1-z) * y$b + y$c) how can we do this?

Comment: The only reason that I did not delete my answer, is that this is yet another example of "find the matrix multiplication" and mine just might be good for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this (prior to the edit of the question, `x` and `y` are of length 2):

```
d <- list(x, y)
t(sapply(d,  function(x) z*x$a + (1-z)*x$b))
##      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]     [,9] [,10]
## [1,]    2 1.888889 1.777778 1.666667 1.555556 1.444444 1.333333 1.222222 1.111111     1
## [2,]    5 4.888889 4.777778 4.666667 4.555556 4.444444 4.333333 4.222222 4.111111     4
```